# Aggregate data into days, weeks, months for Flot time chart

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I would like to create charts similar to Google Analytics which allow you to aggregate data by day, week, month...

As an example, the following chart data displays daily data for a month:

[image]

And by clicking 'Week', the chart aggregates the data points into weeks:

[image]

The closest I can find is the Ruby library Timeslicer, https://github.com/Trimeego/timeslicer . Is there something similar in Javascript or a Flot plugin out there?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Have you with tried http://www.jqplot.com/ ?

It is easy to use... but if you use MVC I would use the Char built in object. Anyway, I hope this can help you!

Comment: Hi,
Could you point me to a demo using jqplot which accomplishes the same goal? Thanks.